Lock Ubuntu 24.04 after idle without screen blank
I'm running a Sunshine remote desktop server which currently depends on kmsgrab, so screen blanking causes it to not be able to capture the display. (I hope this is resolved when it migrates to either xdg portals or the new Wayland capture API, but we'll see!)
This means I've had to enable autologin, set "Screen Blank" / "Blank Screen Delay" to 'never', and set "Automatic Suspend" to off. However, the result is that there is no idle screen locking, because automatic screen lock is tied to screen blank.
I tested xdg-screensaver lock and that works! It triggers the lockscreen and blacks out (but not blanks) the display. I can hack a script together, but I wanted to ask:

What would be the best practice way of automatically going to lockscreen after 5 minutes of idle without screen blanking?

Autologon is another annoying problem, otherwise it can't capture anything, but that's a problem for another day.
